# Reduce CloudFlare Wait Time

Tags: performance, page-speed, cloudflare

I installed CloudFlare as a test to one domain on my server, supposing it would be quicker. But it's not. The waiting time (I think, otherwise known as time to first byte) has gone up considerably.

Is there any way to reduce this? I believe CloudFlare carries out lots of tests, which I am guessing is what is causing this increased wait time. Is there a way to turn all this off? I'm just interested in what their improvements to DNS and TLS time is.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off all CloudFlare's features except DNS:

1. Log into your account
2. Select the domain
3. Go to your overview page
4. Scroll down to advanced:

[image]

and disable CloudFlare.

This just leaves you with CloudFlare DNS.